# How to compare two array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    let seat = [3,6,4, 34]
    let allS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
```

I have two array i want to get a array from these two array which does not have any value which is in seat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const filtered = allS.filter(n => !seat.includes(n));
```